# The number of ways for an increasing sequence with same parity

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose a $k$ member sequence with $1 \leq k \leq n $ is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots, a_k\}$. How many such sequences satisfy $1\leq a_1 < a_2 < \cdots 
> < a_k \leq n$ and $a_i \equiv i \pmod 2$?

I'm thinking of building a bijection from this sequence to another sequence. I'm thinking that $d_i$ could be the difference between two terms, but having them sum to a constant so we could apply stars and bars. Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that if $n$ has different parity from $k$, then the condition $a_k \leq n$ is equivalent to $a_k \leq n - 1$, since $a_k$ has the same parity as $k$ and therefore cannot equal $n$.  So it's enough to solve the problem in the case where $k$ and $n$ have the same parity, because this gives you the answers for the other case as well.

For the $a_i$ to alternate parity and increase means that the successive differences $d_i := a_{i+1} - a_i$ are all odd positive integers.  So let's write $d_i = 2 m_i + 1$.

Now we have

$$a_k = a_{k-1} + (2m_{k-1} + 1) = \cdots = a_1 + 2(m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1}) + (k-1)$$

So we can write the condition $a_k \leq n$ as

$$a_1 + 2(m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1}) \leq n - k + 1.$$

The $m_i$ here are non-negative, whereas $a_1$ is necessarily positive.  I don't love this, so let's write $a_1 := b + 1$.  That gives us

$$b + 2(m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1}) \leq n - k.$$

Let's write $\Delta$ for the difference between the left- and right-hand sides here, so that we can express this as an equation

$$b + 2(m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1}) + \Delta  = n - k$$

Since we're considering the case where $k$ and $n$ have the same parity, the right-hand side here is even.  It follows that $b$ and $\Delta$ have the same parity.

Consider the case where both are even.  (The case where both are odd can be solved analogously.)  Then we can write $b = 2c$ and $\Delta = 2\delta$, giving us all together the expression

$$2(c + m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1} + \delta) = n - k$$

Or in other words

$$c + m_1 + \cdots + m_{k-1} + \delta = \frac{n - k}{2}$$

So we want to know in how many ways the number $(n-k)/2$ can be written as the sum of $(k+1)$ nonnegative integers.

Can you take things from here?

Comment: I think I can take it from here. By stars and bars the number of ways is $\dbinom{\frac{n-k}{2}+k}{k}$.

Comment: Since $k \leq n$ couldn't $a_k=n$ be possible?

Comment: Yes.  Did I say it wasn't?